# Filemaker auto enter calculation - update with relationship

Tags: filemaker

According to the Filemaker documentation,

> If you select Calculated value, you can edit the field value in Browse mode (if Prohibit modification of value isn't selected). The value is calculated when you create a record, or when one of the referenced fields changes and the destination field is empty. (However, if you select Do not evaluate if all referenced fields are empty in the Specify Calculation dialog box, the value isn't calculated when you create a record and all fields referenced by the calculation are empty. Instead, the value is calculated when one of the referenced fields contains a value.

An auto enter calculation will be calculated if the reference field value used in the calculation is changed. I'm using a field in the relationship and from that same relationship I'm getting the value from a related table.

For example, relationship between table A to B is based on a field F1. In my calculation, I've

```
B::__text
```

Here, in this calculation I'm not using the field F1 but it used in the relationship between A->B. Whenever I'm changing the value of F1, Filemaker is updating the value of the auto enter calculation.

Is this normal? I don't find any docs related to this in the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is expected behavior as long as the "Do not replace existing value of field" is not selected.

Comment: Ok, So I need to consider the relationship as well. Right ?

Comment: Changes in fields from related tables does not update an Auto Enter calculation, but changes in any of the local key fields used in the relationship will update any calculation where the relationship is used, unless the beforementioned option is not selected.